# Reduce number of joins in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization

I have 12 fixed tables (group, local, element, sub_element, service, ...), each table with different numbers of rows.

The columns 'id_' in all table is a primary key (int). The others columns are of datatype `varchar(20)`. The maximum number of rows in these tables are 300.

Each table was created in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE group 
(
    id_G int NOT NULL,
    name_group varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_G)
);

|........GROUP......|    |.......LOCAL.......|    |.......SERVICE.......|          
| id_G | name_group |    | id_L | name_local |    | id_S | name_service | 
+------+------------+    +------+------------+    +------+--------------+
|   1  |   group1   |    |   1  |   local1   |    |   1  |   service1   |
|   2  |   group2   |    |   2  |   local2   |    |   2  |   service2   |
```

And I have one table that combine all these tables depending on user selects.
The 'id_' come from fixed tables selected by the user are recorded into this table.

This table was crate in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE group 
(
    id_E int NOT NULL,
    event_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    id_G int NOT NULL,
    id_L int NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (id_G)
);
```

The tables (event) look like this:

```
|....................EVENT.....................|          
| id_E | event_name  | id_G | id_L | ... |id_S | 
+------+-------------+------+------+-----+-----+
|   1  |  mater1     |   1  |   1  | ... |  3  |
|   2  |  master2    |   2  |   2  | ... |  6  |
```

This table get greater each day, an now it has about thousunds of rows.
Column `id_E` is the primary key (int), `event_name` is varchar(20).

This table has, in addition of id_E and event_name columns, 12 other columns the came from the fixed tables.

Every time than I need to retrieve information on the event table, to turn more readable, I need to do about 12 joins.

My query look like this where i need to retrieve all columns from table event:

```
SELECT event_name, name_group, name_local ..., name_service 
FROM event 
INNER JOIN group on event.id_G = group.id_G
INNER JOIN local on event.id_L = local.id_L
...
INNER JOIN service on event.id_S = service.id_S
WHERE event.id_S = 7 (for example)
```

This slows down my system performance. Is there a way to reduce the number of joins? I've heard about using Natural Keys, but I think this is not a good idea to form my case thinking in future maintenance.

My queries are taking about 7 seconds and I need to reduce this time.
I changed the WHERE clause and this caused not affect. So, I am sure that the problem is that the query has so many joins.

Could someone give some help? thanks a lot...

Comment: Welcome. As we all can see, you didn't pay attention to the preview before posting this.... It would be nice if you would format your question so it becomes readable.

Comment: A 12 table join seems excessive. I think you’re using the wrong tech or you’ve over-engineered the schema. Consider saving the full join into a NoSQL db and querying that instead.

Comment: If the **WHERE something.**  from the table event you can use a subselect. to reduce the row like **SELECT ... FROM (SELECT  * FROM event WHERE xxx= ) as e INNER JOIN ... **

Comment: Trincot, thak you for you observation. I will trie to put the real structure of my table here. All 12 tables are similar and my query is too simple like i had put in my question.

Comment: @Brend, In my query i need these joins only yo retrieve data from the 'SELECT'. I not need theses joins to put some condition in the "WHERE' clause, so i think i cant do this. I need to get all 12 columns data (name_) from event table.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable minimal code & minimal representative data given as code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. [ask]

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: "Reduce the number of joins" sounds like the solution to an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). You _should_ be optimizing your query, but reducing the number of joins might not be the most effective solution. When you ask a query-optimization question, you should include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <name>` for each table referenced in the query, and the output of `EXPLAIN <query>`. Don't make us guess at what indexes and data types you currently have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL has a great keyword of "STRAIGHT_JOIN" and might be what you are looking for.  First, each of your lookup tables (id/description) I have to assume already have an index on the ID column since that is primary key.

Your event table is the one you are querying as the primary basis of the details and joining to the lookups per their respective IDs.  As long as your WHERE clause applicable to the EVENT table is optimized, such as the ID you are looking for, it SHOULD be virtually instantaneous.

If it is not, then it might be that MySQL is trying to think for you and take one of the secondary lookup tables and make it a primary basis of the query for whatever reason, such as much lower record count.  In this case, add the keyword and try it..

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN  ... rest of your query
```

This tells MySQL to do the query in the order you gave it, thus the Event table first and it's where clause on the ID.  It should find that one thing, then grab all the corresponding lookup descriptions from the other tables.

Comment: Great... This saved my query. Now it runs instantly. So there is no need to reduce the joins, but to direct mysql on the joins.

Answer (score -1):

Create [indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html), concretely use compound indexes, for instance, start creating a compound index for event and groups:

- on table events create one for (event id, group id).
- then, on the group table create another one for the next relation (group id, local id).
- on local do the same with service, and so on...

Comment: How do you KNOW that this problem is about indexes? (my best guess is that you are right), but its remains guessing. An answer will stop paulo from doing and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64079756/edit) on his question to get things readable.

Comment: All the id_ columns in each table are primary key. So i think the index is not the problem. Am i correct ?

Comment: I'm talking about composite indexes paulo, you're correct: every primary/unique key will be an index although a single one.